# How can we know the number of deleted and edited posts?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is there any way to find the **number of deleted posts** and **number of edited posts** on Stack Exchange Meta in a specific period of time?

Comment: you need a query on sede

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're looking for this information? What problem would you be able to solve with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1385627?start=2021-01-01&end=2021-03-01) does that:

```
select
(
select count(*) 
from postswithdeleted
where deletiondate between ##start:string?2021-01-01## 
                   and     ##end:string?2021-03-01##
) deleted                   
, 
(
select count(distinct postid) [edited]
from posthistory 
where posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6,7,8,9) -- edit / rollback
and creationdate between ##start:string?2021-01-01## 
                   and     ##end:string?2021-03-01##
) edited
```

When run today for the period between Jan, 1st 2021 and Mar, 1st 2021 this is the result

[image: edited 1,294; deleted 11,008]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).